# Найти в диапазоне таблицы от A1 до A1000 значение

Tags: javascript, vba

Необходимо найти первое совпадающее значение в диапазоне таблицы от A1 до А1000.
И выделить все ячейки начиная от найденой, заканчивая A1000.
Сделал такое на VBA а в JS не получается.

```
Dim a As String
Dim c As Range
a = TextBox3.Text
    For Each c In [A1:A1000]
        If c.Value = a Then
           c.Offset(0).Select
           Exit For
        End If
Next

If ActiveCell.Text = a Then
g = ActiveCell.AddressLocal(-1)
Range(g, "$A$1").Interior.Color = vbWhite
Range(g, "$A$1").Font.Color = vbBlack
cat = ActiveCell.AddressLocal
Range(cat, "$A$1000").Interior.Color = vbBlue
Range(cat, "$A$1000").Font.Color = vbWhite
Label3.Caption = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(cat, "$A$1000"))
Else
MsgBox ("Такого занчения не найдено!")
End If
```

Заполняю сначала значения в js так

```
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=СЛУЧМЕЖДУ($E$3;$F$3');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A1000'), 
  SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A1000').activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант в *VBA*. Ячейку выделять не обязательно.

```
Sub FindValue()
Dim c As Range
Dim a As Double, bFlag As Boolean
    a = TextBox3.Text

    For Each c In [A1:A1000]
        If c.Value = a Then
            With Range(c, [A1000])
                .Interior.Color = vbBlue: .Font.Color = vbWhite
            End With

            With Range([A1], c)
                .Interior.Color = vbWhite: .Font.Color = vbBlack
            End With

            Label3.Caption = Application.Sum(Range(c, [A1000]))
            bFlag = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next c

    If bFlag = False Then MsgBox "Значение " & a & " не найдено!", 64, ""
End Sub
```

Comment: А в JS Вы не могли бы такое сделать?

Comment: Увы, там я не умею )